# JavaScript compare strings such that letters come before other characters

Tags: javascript, string, string-comparison

How can you compare two strings in JavaScript such that letters will come before other characters? I'm specifically interested in letters coming before the underscore character, but would prefer a general solution.

For example, the code below will return -1, but I'd like it to return 1.

```
const a = "_";
const b = "A";
return a.localeCompare(b);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A better explanation of your use case and some samples with expected results would be helpful here

Comment: It seems I can use the ==, <, and > operators to get the result I'm wanting. However, I suspect there may be a way to configure localeCompare, but I haven't been able to figure that out yet.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this simple regex solution

```js
const isLetter = x => /[A-Za-z]/.test(x)

const compare = (a, b) => {
  if (!isLetter(a) && isLetter(b)) return 1
  if (isLetter(a) && !isLetter(b)) return -1
  return a.localeCompare(b)
}

console.log(
  compare('_', 'A')
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll resort to using this kind of custom logic if needed. I was just holding on to some hope that I'd be able to avoid rolling my own solution.